# Meaning of 棒立ちの様子

Tags: translation, meaning

I got this sentence from [Boku no Hero S01E13 (06m25s)](https://animelon.com/video/5ac58616f1fe4e742d177a21)

> それにどうやら子供らは棒立ちの様子です.
>   Besides, the children appear to be frozen in fear. (translation from the site)

I understand everything except the expresion in the title.

According to Rikaikun, those words mean:
棒立ち= standing upright; standing bolt upright; rearing
様子 = state; state of affairs; situation; circumstances;

So how can 棒立ちの様子 mean "frozen in fear"?

Comment: Does it make more sense if you reword the translation as "scared stiff"?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

棒立ち literally means "standing (like a) stick", and its implication is "uselessly standing still without doing anything else". "In fear" is a translator's addition, but I think it's not spot-on because the children don't seem to be afraid in particular.

Comment: I think it makes sense if you use that meaning you described. "Besides, the children are just standing there doing nothing."